# PHP Arrays and $_POST acting strange

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="plusfri[]" value="Fri"> Friday 
<input type="checkbox" name="plussat[]" value="Sat"> Saturday 
<input type="checkbox" name="plussun[]" value="Sun"> Sunday
<input type="checkbox" name="plusmon[]" value="Mon"> Monday
```

That posts to the following PHP:

```
$plus = array(array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => ""));

    foreach($_POST['plusname'] as $k => $p)
    {
        $plus[$k]['Name'] = $p;
        $plus[$k]['Age'] = $_POST['plusage'][$k];
        $plus[$k]['Conc'] = $_POST['plusconc'][$k];
        $plus[$k]['Days'] = "X";
        if($_POST['plusfri'][$k]=="Fri") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "1"; 
        if($_POST['plussat'][$k]=="Sat") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "2"; 
        if($_POST['plussun'][$k]=="Sun") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "3"; 
        if($_POST['plusmon'][$k]=="Mon") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "4"; 
    }
```

And I end up with:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "FRISAT"
    ["Days"]=>
    string(3) "X12"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Conc"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "SATSUn"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Conc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Days"]=>
    string(3) "X23"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "SUNMON"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Conc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Days"]=>
    string(3) "X34"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why 'Days' has jumped to the end on only elements [1] and [2] ??>

Comment: Why to care ? Does it matter ?

Comment: Not really, but it doesnt make sense.  And when things dont make sense, its very annoying.

Comment: code optimization? secret php function? apache thread? who cares? you just have your correct data, is enough ;)

Comment: It's pretty simple: when you declared the array you put the `days` key second. This can be accessed at `$plus[0]['days']`. `0` is the first index used in the foreach statement so for the first array `days` is in second place. After that the keys are set in the order they're defined and so `days` is last. To make them all uniform use: `$plus = array(array("Name" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => "", "Days" => ""));`

Comment: Lol, Why doesnt anyone else care!  They should all be in order and they arn't,  and no one knows why.

Comment: @Chud37 - Babs Seed's answer explains this correctly.

Comment: In PHP you shouldn't ever care or pay attention to the order of associative arrays. They are hashmaps and certainly shouldn't be expected to be in any given order, that's the nature of hashmaps.. If order mattered you'd use numerically indexed arrays instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of your loop. To get the same key order, you should set the value in the same order too, like this :

```
$plus = array(array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => ""));

foreach($_POST['plusname'] as $k => $p)
{
    $plus[$k]['Name'] = $p;
    $plus[$k]['Days'] = "X"; // <-- see ?
    $plus[$k]['Age'] = $_POST['plusage'][$k];
    $plus[$k]['Conc'] = $_POST['plusconc'][$k];
    if($_POST['plusfri'][$k]=="Fri") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "1"; 
    if($_POST['plussat'][$k]=="Sat") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "2"; 
    if($_POST['plussun'][$k]=="Sun") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "3"; 
    if($_POST['plusmon'][$k]=="Mon") $plus[$k]['Days'] .= "4"; 
}
```

Comment: This is the reason for the ordering of `$plus[1]` and `$plus[2]`, but has nothing to do with the ordering of `$plus[0]` which is because he declared the structure of that array outside the loop as Babs Seed said.

Comment: Aaah! That is quite strange behavoir though? Why should modifying it immediately change the ordering?  Anyway, thank you for clearing tha up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared the ordering of `$plus[0]` outside the loop, when you run the first loop iteration you are replacing the value assignments of the variables within `$plus[0]`. In subsequent iterations, because you haven't pre-declared `$plus[1]`, `$plus[2]` etc you are assigning entirely new variables to an *empty* array.

Try this instead if you want to preserve ordering:

```
$plus = array();

foreach($_POST['plusname'] as $k => $p)
{
    $plusChild = array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => "");
    $plusChild['Name'] = $p;
    $plusChild['Age'] = $_POST['plusage'][$k];
    $plusChild['Conc'] = $_POST['plusconc'][$k];
    $plusChild['Days'] = "X";
    if($_POST['plusfri'][$k]=="Fri") $plusChild['Days'] .= "1"; 
    if($_POST['plussat'][$k]=="Sat") $plusChild['Days'] .= "2"; 
    if($_POST['plussun'][$k]=="Sun") $plusChild['Days'] .= "3"; 
    if($_POST['plusmon'][$k]=="Mon") $plusChild['Days'] .= "4"; 
    $plus[$k] = $plusChild;
}
```

Alternatively, you could replace this:

```
$plus = array(array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => ""));
```

With this:

```
$plus = array(array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => ""),array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => ""),array("Name" => "", "Days" => "", "Age" => "","Conc" => ""));
```

But this will only work if you know you will always have three returns.

Comment: Thank you! Still seems quite strange though!

Comment: @Chud37 - Not really. You've declared the ordering of `$plus[0]` outside the loop, so all you're doing in the first loop iteration is replacing those values. In subsequent loop iterations, because you haven't predeclared `$plus[1]`, `$plus[2]` etc, the order of the variables is the order you specify them in the loop. In the first iteration you are replacing values, in subsequent iterations you are creating new variables.